# Accordion inside modal - When click on any other collapsible tab, the first one remain open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I open the modal the first tab by default opens up and if I click on any other tab the first tab closes and the clicked tab opens up, but then If I again click on the first tab then both the tabs opens up. Here is the html code

```
    <body>
<button id="modalButtton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>   
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 id="modal-title"> </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Course Introduction

                                </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>

                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Description

                                </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>

                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Goals

                                </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>

                            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod te</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div> <!-- end of Modal -->

</body>
```

Here is the jquery code

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
$('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
$('#collapseOne').collapse('show');
});



$('#accordion').find('.panel-default:has(".in")').addClass('panel-primary');

$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
$(e.target).closest('.panel-default').addClass(' panel-primary');
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
$(e.target).closest('.panel-default').removeClass(' panel-primary');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to call `$('.collapse').collapse('hide');` inside your function for `show.bs.collapse`:

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $(e.target).closest('.panel-default').addClass(' panel-primary');
  $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $(e.target).closest('.panel-default').removeClass(' panel-primary');
})
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/ppq7f4qn/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You answered just as I was about to. To add to the answer, you can remove `$('#accordion').find().addClass()` in the JS, as well the `in` class in the `#collapseOne` element. This is because on `shown.bs.modal` you already toggle the collapse which fires the `show.bs.collapse` anyway. (in the code posted by OP by the way!)